# C - writing output to a file

Tags: c, io, fopen, printf, fclose

```
EDIT: 

void print(const int *v, const int size) {
 FILE *fpIn;
 fpIn = fopen("char-array.txt", "a");
 int i;  
 if (v != 0) {
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     printf("%d", (int)v[i]);
     fprintf(fpIn, "%d\n", (int)v[i]);   
   }
   perm_count++;
   printf("\n");
 }
 fclose(fpIn);
}
```

I guess this is a relatively simple question :)

Basically the program is using a permutation algorithm, and printing the output to standard output in the console. I also want to write the content to a file via fprintf I assume. Though I cant seem to get it working. It just prints garbage characters into the first line in the text file and nothing more !

I will paste the code below, and help is much appreciated ! The write to file code is found within the print function.

Thanks,

T.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <time.h>
clock_t startm, stopm;
#define START if ( (startm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define STOP if ( (stopm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define PRINTTIME printf("%2.3f seconds used by the processor.", ((double)stopm-          startm)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

int perm_count = 0; 

void print(const int *v, const int size) {
  FILE *fpIn;
  fpIn = fopen("char-array.txt", "wb");
  int i;  
  if (v != 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%d", (char)v[i]);
      fprintf(fpIn, "%d", v[i]);  
      fprintf(fpIn, "\n");  
    }
    perm_count++;
    printf("\n");
  }
} 


void permute(int *v, const int start, const int n) {  
  int i;  
  if (start == n-1) {
    print(v, n);
  }
  else {
    for (i = start; i < n; i++) {
      int tmp = v[i];
      v[i] = v[start];
      v[start] = tmp;
      permute(v, start+1, n);
      v[start] = v[i];
      v[i] = tmp;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
 int i, x;
 printf("Please enter the number of terms: ");
 scanf("%d", &x);
 int arr[x];   
 printf("Please enter the terms: ");
 for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
 scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
 START
 permute(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
 STOP   
 printf("Permutation Count: %d\n", perm_count);
 PRINTTIME
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest less reliance on macros for tasks that can be easily handled via functions instead.

Comment: +1 @sarnold.  Your future debugging self will thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Incorrect access modes in [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) call**
You open your file as a *binary file*: `fopen("char-array.txt", "wb");`. Don't put `b` to this string containing *access modes* if you are going to write formatted strings there. And since you probably want to append new data at the end of the file instead of overwritting them, use `a` instead of `w`:

```
fopen("char-array.txt", "a");
```

**2. Writing to the output buffer, not directly into the file**
When you are using functions like [fprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), you don't write directly to the file but to the output buffer. You have to use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) to write data from the output buffer into the file, or you can just close your file by using [fclose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) function which flushes this buffer automatically.

Just add this line:

```
fclose(fpIn);
```

at the end of `print` function.

**3. Incorrect formatting of the output**
You should not cast `int` to `char`. It will truncate your numbers. And you also have `fprintf(fpIn, "\n");` in wrong scope I guess. It could look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  printf("%d ", v[i]);
  fprintf(fpIn, "%d ", v[i]);
}
perm_count++;
printf("\n");
fprintf(fpIn, "\n");
```

Comment: Also, depending on the operating system, it might be an issue that the file is being opened for binary write ("wb").

Comment: I have made the changes, but still seem to be getting garbage output ? See the edit :)

Comment: Just taken your edit into account, thanks :) However, the output in notepad is just random ASCII characters.

Comment: _@LihO_. Why `you don't write directly to the file but to the output buffer` and how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @user: Let's say in most of cases your disc has better things to do than taking care of each `fprintf` call. What you write to file is actually written to it once the buffer is flushed (for example when file is closed by calling `fclose`).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your words. Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time doing programming you don't have to, the use of `fprintf` is nice but since all you want to do is print the output, you can just print things into the file directly using UNIX built-in commands. Say your program is called `wirteoutput` then all you have to do is pass the following command when calling it from the shell `writeoutput > file.txt`. All you would have to use would be the `printf` function.

If you are curious about this, this is an old function and you can find a detailed description in the original paper [The UNIX Operating System](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2004/readings/ritchie74unix.pdf). Look at the section called Standard I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't cast to a `char` (from a `int`) when you wrote to the file as you did with the screen display.  The following will provide the same numbers in the file as you're seeing on screen:

```
fprintf(fpIn, "%d", (char)v[i]);
```